# CSS: Trying to center some elements

Tags: html, css, center

Hy there. I'm macking an HTML/CSS tutorial and I'm facing some problems with positioning and those stuff. I got 3 stacked elements at my header and want them to be at the very center.

[image]

So I try something like this:

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 940px;
}
```

at my CSS code, and add this class to those elements. It is recognizing the comands, since it moved a bit. But not the way I expected:

[image]

It remanied at the left, just a few more steps to the right. Funny part is: if I put something like

```
.container {
  margin: auto 50% auto 50%;
  width: 940px;
}
```

it's behavior is:

[image]

it GETS centered, but extends the screen lenght and put a scrolling bar. Why? Shoudln't both those options center my elements? What can I do to achieve my goal? I would appreciate an answer so much, since I get a lot of difficulties when trying to understand this part.

Comment: you are centering the container that holds the elements, not the elements themselves. try `.container img { margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: Strange...with "img" it doesn't work, with "p" it does : p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the element is centered fine - it's just still 940 pixels wide, nearly the entire browser, thus not really far from the left edge. If you want to center its *contained elements* as well, just add `text-align:center` to it.

To see better what's happening, consider temporarily adding a `background:red` to the element and a lot will be clearer. It makes learning CSS tons easier to actually see the 'boxes' of the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) doing their job.

In your second example you appear to be confusing the order of values of the `margin` declaration. You're actually giving it a left and right margin of 50%, putting its *left edge* indeed right in the center. The 940 pixels width then make it stretch off to the right, still 940px wide, causing the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container { text-align:center }
```

Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This would be straight forward to solve if you added your html as well.